# search for a string in file and change the next line using awk

Tags: linux, string, awk, replace

I have a very specific problem, I want to search for the line containing the first word
*Contro_Contact in file1 and when it is found I want to replace the line which comes after that 2 rows downs with another line from anthor file2 so that the parameter are changed automatically fom the file 2

```
*CONTROL_CONTACT
$#  slsfac    rwpnal    islchk    shlthk    penopt    thkchg     orien    enmass
0.100000     0.000         2         1         4         0         1         0
```

The output could be

```
*CONTROL_CONTACT
$#  slsfac    rwpnal    islchk    shlthk    penopt    thkchg     orien    enmass
0.2340000     0.000         2         1         4         0         1         0
```

The changed line I have from another file so its not the problem.

I will be waiting for experts suggestions.

Comment: which language/operating system? what have you tried so far? this isn't a "give me the codez" site :)

Comment: I have tried with Linux .. but I am new to it, I can do it with MATLAB but I need it with linux, as I am new so I am trying to learn from the tips. when will tell me once I note it and change it as per need and repost , if somebody wants so :)  http://stackoverflow.com/users/62951/antony-scott

Comment: it will help people help you if you tag your question appropriately. if you're using linux it sounds like you could use something like grep. I'm not a linux/unix expert so can't give you much more than that. I do know there are existing tools that do this kind of thing.

Comment: you could try it with sed or perl and a regular expression that matches the first line incl the \n and then replace something in the next line

Comment: thanks scott and roex, I had tried with Awk , and I am trying to do using Awk , if Ihttp://stackoverflow.com/users/446140/reox am successful I will also post the solution regards, http://stackoverflow.com/users/62951/antony-scotthe http://stackoverflow.com/users/62951/antony-scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'N != 0 || $0 != "*CONTROL_CONTACT"
  N == 0 && $0 =="*CONTROL_CONTACT"{
    N = 1; print; getline; print
    getline; getline < "file2"; print}' file1
```

Comment: I misunderstood the problem.  I thought that only the 1st occurrence of '*CONTROL_CONTACT' needed to process.  Remove the N code to process all occurrences.

Comment: that was perfect, how ever with awk , is it possible to change in place like we can do with                                                               sed -i -e                                                         what you have aleady told me. I mean it is possible to write a new file , rename and and the delete this original file and rename the old one , or put in temporary folder.

Comment: Nope, `awk` doesn't have the equivalent of Perl's and some `sed`s' `-i` option, for in-place editing.

Comment: ok.. http://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee   thanks for the answer, i mananged to do it by swaping the file to temporary folder.   thanks-  http://stackoverflow.com/users/851677/jfgagne  for your guidence also , as I am near to completion of my code.. warm regards

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e '/^\*CONTROL_CONTACT/{n;n;r file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

or this (bash only):

```
sed '/^\*CONTROL_CONTACT/{n;n;r file2'$'\n'';d}' file1
```

or if there are multiple `CONTROL_CONTACT`'s and multiple parameters in file 2 (GNU sed only):

```
sed -e '/^\*CONTROL_CONTACT/{n;n;R file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

Comment: you code worked fine but the problem is that, in command prompt it works fine but in the shell script is gives an error that 50 chracters are extra on the line. http://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong

Comment: @hamaskhan it may be your shell is not bash, use the 1st or 3rd solutions

Comment: it also worked perfectly , thanks potong..  it was a nice compact form code.http://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -r "/^\*CONTROL_CONTACT/{n;n;s/^\S*/$(head -1 file2)/p;d}" file1
```